# Need advice on configuring a formula/validation on a numeric field

Tags: formula-field, validation, custom-field

I am fairly new to Salesforce and was hoping one of you experts can help me in configuring a numeric field correctly.

Basically I need a field that can have an initial value entered, which will then be considered its default value. The field value can be incremented or added to but cannot be decreased. So if the field value is set to 5, only values above 5 can be added and nothing below 5.

I have tried researching different functions and came across PRIORVALUE to evaluate the initial value and then enforce a condition that the new value cannot be below it. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or if there are any other functions I should consider to meet this requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That approach sounds reasonable. It rather depends on what User Experience you want and whether this is an absolute requirement, or something that is just a warning. Remember to allow for validation in the initial creation of the record too.

Comment: Just once thing to add to @Phil W comment to consider. If in the future you plan to Update these records in bulk, for example from a csv using dataloader, a validation rule will slow down your process since they are not bulkified. In that case you will probably end up chosing another tool like triggers or flows.

Comment: Appreciate the comments and insight on different things to consider. Glad to know I was on the right path, thank you.